# Display math in \savebox?

Tags: tables, math-mode, subfloats, subcaption, box

As per the title, I'm trying to utilize display math in a savebox to get the width of the display math:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\sbox{\mybox}{\[ 2 + 2 \]}

\begin{document}
    \usebox{\mybox}
\end{document}
```

However, this fails with "Bad math environment delimiter". What is the solution to this? Is it wrong to even use a savebox here?

For more context, I'm trying to automatically calculate the width of the displaymath to calculate the width of the `subtable` (from the `subcaption` package) needed for a displaymath `array`.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: The use of `\[...\]` requires vertical mode, whereas `\sbox` is trying to collect its contents in horizontal mode.  The alternative is to say `\sbox\mybox{$\displaystyle 2+2$}`.  This creates a horizontal box of width equal to the content, while instructing the content to be set in `\displaystyle`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

display math like a paragraph is always full width (`\hsize`) so to store in a box you need to use a `\parbox` so it can hold vertical material

```
\sbox{\mybox}{\parbox{4cm}{\[ 2 + 2 \]}}
```

will work but not be any use for the stated intention of measuring the width as it will be the width of the parbox, 4cm, known in advance.

What you can instead do is measure the natural width of the math set as inline math in display style

```
\sbox{\mybox}{$\displaystyle 2 + 2 $}
```